# Flask Cors Policy blocking requests

Tags: cors, flask-restful

Attempting to pass requests to my Flask-Rest API using CORS and I cannot get the two to talk because of a CORS block.
I have a website: https://example.com and my restapi is at https://example.com:5000

My Python (Using Flask RestAPI) code:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(ProductionConfig)

CORS(app,resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}},supports_credentials=True)

api = Api(app)

@app.after_request
def add_cors_headers(response):
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin',"https://example.com")
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials','true')
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Methods',"GET,POST,OPTIONS,HEAD")
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Headers',"Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization")
```

Console Error:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://example.com:5000/folders?page=1&limit=25&loader=false' from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Not understanding why it says:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I could really use some help here getting this site online.  Any help is appreciated